# Change location of onclick function after form is processed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using this button to close an form when it is shown to the user before the form is processed.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="submit_delete_dismiss_calc" onclick="window.location.reload()">Close</button>
```

After the form is successfully processed the location does not longer exists so I need to change the location to

```
dossier_detail_folders.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

Therefor I have added to exisitng JS:

```
$("#submit_delete_dismiss_calc"+formid).setAttribute("onClick", "location.href='dossier_detail_folders.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>'");
```

And that gives the console error:
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setAttribute is not a function`

The rest of the JS has no issues, how to get the location changed correctly?
My complete JS:

```
// delete_calc
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", ".delete_calc", function() {
        formid=($(this).attr("alt"));
        subform_delete_calc(formid);
    });
});
function subform_delete_calc(formid)
{
       $("#submit_delete_dismiss_calc"+formid).hide();
       $("#submit_delete_calc"+formid).hide();
       $("#submit_delete_spinner_calc"+formid).show();

       var postData = $("#delete_calc"+formid).serializeArray();
       var formURL='processing/calculatie_delete.php';
        $.ajax({
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#modal_delete_calc'+formid+' .modal-body').html(data);

                $("#submit_delete_spinner_calc"+formid).hide();
                $("#submit_delete_dismiss_calc"+formid).show();
                $("#submit_delete_dismiss_calc"+formid).setAttribute("onClick", "location.href='dossier_detail_folders.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>'");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log(status + ": " + error);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setAttribute` is javascript native method and is not part of jquery. You can use [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to add attribute using jquery

```
$("#submit_delete_dismiss_calc"+formid)
.attr("onClick", "location.href='dossier_detail_folders.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>'");
```

Comment: Yes! Would be nice if alle problems were this easy to solve.